# QGIS distribution with automatic installation of plugins

Tags: qgis, installation

in our company we use QGIS 3.4.8LTR. We install qgis on every PC via distribution software. We manage the user settings with the **qgis_global_settings.ini**. So we can ensure that every user has the same settings.

Now we are searching for a possibility to manage the installtion of plugins. With the update on a new QGIS version we want, that every user has a pre-selection of plugins automatically installed.

How can we manage that?

Comment: Since the plugins are stored in the user profile, you can start QGIS with a shared profile path and put all the plugins into the central profile, see https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#label-commandline

Comment: @joe_gerner did you ever find an answer to this question? I'm trying to do the same thing.